# How to make listen gem work with Ruby 3.0.0p0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, listen

I installed Ruby 3.0.0p0 on my Macbook pro (2020 M1) and rails 6.1.3. However, whenever attempting to start up the rails server on my machine, I get the following error:

```
listen-3.2.1 requires ruby version >= 2.2.7, ~> 2.2, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 3.0.0p0
```

Really need to get this up and running. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upgrade the version of listen gem. There are newer versions available: https://rubygems.org/gems/listen/versions/3.1.5

So if there is a version specified in the gem file, remove it and run `bundle update listen`

You might need to play around a bit with different version, in case bundler doesn't find a version that matches with all other dependiencies of your app.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: If it worked I am happy if you could accedpt my answer

Comment: if you're here because of Jekyll, what helped was removing `gemfile.lock`, `brew update && brew upgrade`, `brew install vips`, and as @muya_'s answer suggests, `bundle add webrick`. Maybe you need to sprinkle some `bundle update` and/or `gem install bundler jekyll` here and there.

Comment: It should be `bundle update listen `

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to this blog post: https://www.chadduffey.com/2021/03/Jekyll-Poop.html

I was able to solve this issue by running:

```
bundle update
```

and then to solve the subsequent error (when running the Jekyll server):

```
bundle add webrick
```